# C endWord validation; how would you explain this code?

Tags: c, validation

I found this code somewhere, it is for lastword in a string checking validation. It's working well, but how would you explain it?

```
int endWord(char input[], char correctWord[])
{
   if(strlen(input) < strlen(correctWord)) return 0;
   else
   {
       if(strcmp(input + (strlen(input) - strlen(correctWord)), correctWord) == 0) return 1;
       else return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: If `correctWord` content matches the last substring in `input`, the calculation gives where it has to be in `input`, which is `strlen(correctWord)` characters before the terminator of `input`. But it fails if `strlen(correctWord)` > `strlen(input)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: I was writing a fuller answer, when you deleted the question!

Comment: I think it is enough to understand

Comment: It makes me reluctant to devote time to making an answer, if the question vanishes before it is ready.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I am curious about things

Comment: Good for you, it is necessary in the coding world.

Answer (score 0):

Simple to explain: It's a classic buffer overflow / backdoor.

If the string length of the input is less than that of `correctWord`, you are reading past the start of `input`. The comparison will most likely still fail, but most important: It can trigger an access violation. Or worse, is the memory before `input` is under attacker control, this can yield `true` despite not actually matching.

What happens if `input` is long enough had already been explained in the comments.